# I cannot get download Url after upload a file to Firebase Cloud Storage in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I tried to get download Url from Firebase Cloud Storage and save back to Database but after successful file upload to Storage I was getting very strange URL value when I tried to add URL into DB.

```
final String uid = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                                    FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("userImages").child(uid).putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                                            //String imageUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                            String imageUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                            UserModel usermodel = new UserModel();
                                            usermodel.uesrName = name.getText().toString();
                                            usermodel.ProfileImageURL = imageUrl;

                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,imageUrl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


                                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(uid).setValue(usermodel);


                                        }
                                    });
```

From the Storage I can't find URL information but I could find token
[image]

From the DB URL name was very strange and I could see the same name in imageUrl.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
               UserModel usermodel = new UserModel();
               usermodel.uesrName = name.getText().toString();
               usermodel.ProfileImageURL = uri.toString();

               Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,uri.toString()
               FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(uid).setValue(usermodel);
        }
});
```

add on success listener to download url

Comment: Thank you so much!! it works now. Could you please explain why I need to use addOnSuccessListener?

Comment: Download Data via URL [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)

Comment: really appreciate your help!!